# Using all-in-one pygtk installer Windows 7 doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, gtk, pygtk

Hi have installed all in one pygtk and i am getting this famous error "DLL Load Failed"

i ran it with dependency walker, it gave me this error:

```
LoadLibraryExA("c:\python\python27\lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\gtk\_gtk.pyd",  
0x00000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned NULL by thread 1. 
Error: The specified procedure could not be found (127).
```

it shows three .DLL's missing

- LIBGTK-WIN32-2.0-0.DLL
- LIBPANGO-1.0-0.DLL
- LIBPANGOCAIRO-1.0-0.DLL

however, when i look in the runtime folder in the python directory for gtk-2.0
i do see thous three files?

i have also run the check_gtk_install.py script from grimps, that gave me the following:

```
==== Checking with Dependency Walker ====
  Please be patient takes some time
Testing file C:\Python\Python27\Lib/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/_Gtk.pyd
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL      Error dll not found
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL      Error dll not found
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL    Error dll not found
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL   Error dll not found
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL     Error dll not found
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL        Error dll not found
DCOMP.DLL   Error dll not found
GPSVC.DLL   Error dll not found
IESHIMS.DLL         Error dll not found
ERROR: c:\program files (x86)\intel\icls client\MSVCR90.DLL         Version
9.0.30729.6161

MS runtime Version 9.0.30729.6161 loaded from
c:\program files (x86)\intel\icls client\MSVCR90.DLL

MS runtime Version 9.0.30729.6161 loaded from
c:\windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_non
e_50934f2ebcb7eb57\MSVCR90.DLL

Testing file C:\Python\Python27\Lib/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gobject/_GObject.pyd

API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL      Error dll not found
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL      Error dll not found
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL    Error dll not found
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL   Error dll not found
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL     Error dll not found
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL        Error dll not found
DCOMP.DLL   Error dll not found
GPSVC.DLL   Error dll not found
IESHIMS.DLL         Error dll not found
ERROR: c:\program files (x86)\intel\icls client\MSVCR90.DLL         Version
9.0.30729.6161

MS runtime Version 9.0.30729.6161 loaded from
c:\program files (x86)\intel\icls client\MSVCR90.DLL

MS runtime Version 9.0.30729.6161 loaded from
c:\windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_non
e_50934f2ebcb7eb57\MSVCR90.DLL

Testing file C:\Python\Python27\Lib/site-packages/gtk-2.0/pangocairo.pyd
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL      Error dll not found
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL      Error dll not found
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL    Error dll not found
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL   Error dll not found
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL     Error dll not found
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL        Error dll not found
DCOMP.DLL   Error dll not found
GPSVC.DLL   Error dll not found
IESHIMS.DLL         Error dll not found
ERROR: c:\program files (x86)\intel\icls client\MSVCR90.DLL         Version
9.0.30729.6161

MS runtime Version 9.0.30729.6161 loaded from
c:\program files (x86)\intel\icls client\MSVCR90.DLL

MS runtime Version 9.0.30729.6161 loaded from
c:\windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_non
e_50934f2ebcb7eb57\MSVCR90.DLL
```

i would first try to find a solution for this before i try going the hard way and installing all dependency separately (although a i tried that already and it didn't work).

ps, i know this issue has been around for a while, but i couldn't find an answer that works for me, i tried almost all solutions provided here on stackoverflow.

UPDATE: from the above mentioned three DLL files only 1 of each exists on my HDD, unless they are hiding somewhere i can't see.

UPDATE: i don't think these dll files are the problem, because i tried running the demo-gtk.exe file and it works great, if these files would be the problem then the demo shouldn't work, i tried it by removing thous files and running the demo, and it didn't work.. which makes things worse, because now i don't know how to further investigate? does anyone have any suggestions of how to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

followed these instructions

https://www.liamschneider.com/node/9

and for me it was the same problem, i found with ProcMon that import gtk loaded zlib1.dll from SysWOW64 instead of the gtk runtime folder, i deleted it from there and gtk imported fine.